# How to drag items from NSCollectionView

Tags: macos, drag-and-drop, delegates, nscollectionview, nscollectionviewitem

I'm trying to implement dragging items ***from*** an NSCollectionView (not just dropping things on it).

In my example code, I'm registering the CollectionView from dragging:

```
collectionView.registerForDraggedTypes([.URL])
collectionView.setDraggingSourceOperationMask(.every, forLocal: false)
collectionView.setDraggingSourceOperationMask(.every, forLocal: true)
```

Then, I've implemented these methods from the NSCollectionViewDelegate protocol:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, canDragItemsAt indexPaths: Set<IndexPath>, with event: NSEvent) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, pasteboardWriterForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSPasteboardWriting? {    
    return URL(fileURLWithPath: #file) as NSPasteboardWriting
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, draggingSession session: NSDraggingSession, willBeginAt screenPoint: NSPoint, forItemsAt indexPaths: Set<IndexPath>) { }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, draggingSession session: NSDraggingSession, endedAt screenPoint: NSPoint, dragOperation operation: NSDragOperation) { }
```

But neither of them is ever even called!
Why not?

If I add these two methods:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, validateDrop draggingInfo: NSDraggingInfo, proposedIndexPath proposedDropIndexPath: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSIndexPath>, dropOperation proposedDropOperation: UnsafeMutablePointer<NSCollectionView.DropOperation>) -> NSDragOperation {
    return .move
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, acceptDrop draggingInfo: NSDraggingInfo, indexPath: IndexPath, dropOperation: NSCollectionView.DropOperation) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Then I can successfully drop files from the Desktop into the collection view, but still not the other way around.

What's going on?

Best regards, V.

Comment: Is "Selectable" of the collection view switched on?

Comment: @Willeke: I just tried it again with `isSelectable` set to both, `false` and `true`, and it doesn't seem to make any difference at all. :(

Answer (score 0):

Exactly the same here.

It *looks like* a bug  (Xcode 9.4.1, Swit 4.1.2).

Just like you mentioned, `validateDrop` and `acceptDrop` get called in my app.
But (for example), `endedAt` does not:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView,
                    draggingSession session: NSDraggingSession,
                    endedAt screenPoint: NSPoint,
                    dragOperation operation: NSDragOperation) { }
```

The only workaround I could find (for the above `endedAt` delegate) was to subclass `NSCollectionView` (which I'm calling `ImageCollectionView` in the example below) and implement my own `delegate/protocol`:

```
import Cocoa

protocol ImageCollectionViewDelegate {
    func didExitDragging()
}

class ImageCollectionView: NSCollectionView {
    var imageCollectionViewDelegate: ImageCollectionViewDelegate?
}

extension ImageCollectionView {
    override func draggingExited(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo?) {
        super.draggingExited(sender)
        imageCollectionViewDelegate?.didExitDragging()
    }
}
```

(I had to call it `imageCollectionViewDelegate` to not conflict with the already existing `delegate` property.)

Then, in my controller (which I'm calling `ImageCollectionViewController`):

```
@IBOutlet internal weak var imageCollectionView: ImageCollectionView! {
    didSet {
        imageCollectionView.imageCollectionViewDelegate = self
    }
}

extension ImageCollectionViewController: ImageCollectionViewDelegate {
    func didExitDragging() {
        highlightDestination(false)
    }
}
```

That allows me to do stuff when dragging outside the collection.
In this very simple use case, just turning the destination view's highlight on/off:

[image: highlighting]

Ideally all this extra code wouldn't be necessary.

I'm also looking for the proper way of handling this.